# How can I send to DJANGO template the variable of current data?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I need to print the list of persons whose birthdays are today.

I do not know the correct way to introduce the current data variable in the `if` loop.

*personal_list.html*

```
{% for personal in personals %}
{% ifequal personal.data_nastere|date:"d/m" '??/??' %}
    <ul>
        <li><a class="titleOmagiat" href="{% url 'personalomagiat_detail' pk=personal.pk %}">
         {{ personal.name }} {{ personal.surname }} </a>, {{ personal.birth_day|date:"d/m/Y" }}
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

*models.py*

```
 class Personal(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     surname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     birth_day = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

     class Meta:
         ordering = ['name']

     def __str__(self):
         return '%s %s' % (self.name, self.surname)
```

*views.py*

```
def personal_list(request):
    personals = Personal.objects.order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'blog/personal_list.html', {'personals': personals})
```

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^personal/$', views.personal_list, name='personal_list'),
]
```

Tell me the correct answer in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filtering must be done at the database level, not in the template, otherwise you are reading data from disk that you are not using which results in poor performances.

Update your view this way:

```
from django.utils import timezone


def personal_list(request):
    today = timezone.now().date()
    personals = Personal.objects.order_by('name').filter(
        birth_day__month=today.month,
        birth_day__day=today.day)
    return render(request, 'blog/personal_list.html', {'personals': personals})
```

And your template this way:

```
<ul>
  {% for personal in personals %}
    <li><a class="titleOmagiat" href="{% url 'personalomagiat_detail' pk=personal.pk %}">
     {{ personal.name }} {{ personal.surname }} </a>, {{ personal.birth_day|date:"d/m/Y" }}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: my best regards, it definitly works. thanks a lot once again !